# How can I make some videos in the GUI that was designed using qt5 run in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pyqt5, qt5

I have some video in a GUI that plays when certain conditions are met. The problem I have is that I am unable to make the video start again after it ends. Here is the code for the UI:

```
import os 
from time import sleep 
from PyQt5 import uic 
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget 
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget 
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, QUrl 
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer, QMediaPlaylist

class UIThread(QThread): change_pixmap_signal = pyqtSignal(int) current_mode = None new_mode = None
def run(self):
    while True:
        sleep(0.1)
        if self.current_mode != self.new_mode:
            self.current_mode = self.new_mode
            self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(self.current_mode)

class MainUI(QMainWindow): def init(self): super(MainUI, self).init()

    # Load UI from files
    uic.loadUi('ui/main_small.ui', self)
    self.main_label.setPixmap(QPixmap('ui/images/main.png'))
    self.eco_label.setPixmap(QPixmap('ui/images/eco.png'))
    self.ev_mode_label.setPixmap(QPixmap('ui/images/ev_mode.png'))
    self.normal_mode_label.setPixmap(QPixmap('ui/images/normal_mode.png'))
    self.power_mode_label.setPixmap(QPixmap('ui/images/power_mode.png'))
    self.power_mode('N')

    self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
    self.videoWidget = QVideoWidget()
    self.videoWidget.move(0, 0)
    self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.videoWidget)
    self.videoWidget.show()
    self.playlist = QMediaPlaylist()

    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(self.videoWidget)
    self.video_groupBox.setLayout(layout)

    # Default values
    self.mode = None
    self.speed_label.setStyleSheet("color: white")
    self.motor1_speed_label.setStyleSheet("color: white")
    self.motor2_speed_label.setStyleSheet("color: white")
    self.motor3_speed_label.setStyleSheet("color: white")
    self.motor1_torque_label.setStyleSheet("color: white")
    self.motor2_torque_label.setStyleSheet("color: white")
    self.motor3_torque_label.setStyleSheet("color: white")

    # Create the video capture thread
    self.uithread = UIThread()
    # Connect its signal to the update_image slot
    self.uithread.change_pixmap_signal.connect(self.__update_mode)
    self.uithread.start()

# Play videos
def play_video(self, video):
    self.playlist = QMediaPlaylist()
    self.playlist.setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist.Loop)

    if video == 'x':
        self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.getcwd() + '/ui/videos/video_x.mp4')))
    elif video == 'xy':
        self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.getcwd() + '/ui/videos/video_xy.mp4')))
    elif video == 'xyz':
        self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.getcwd() + '/ui/videos/video_xyz.mp4')))
    elif video == 'yz':
        self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.getcwd() + '/ui/videos/video_yz.mp4')))
    elif video == 'z':
        self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.getcwd() + '/ui/videos/video_z.mp4')))
    else:    # zzz
        self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.getcwd() + '/ui/videos/video_zzz.mp4')))
    
    self.mediaPlayer.setPosition(0)
    self.mediaPlayer.setPlaylist(self.playlist)
    self.mediaPlayer.play()

# Change display mode
def change_mode(self, mode):
    self.uithread.new_mode = mode

# Select R N D P mode
def rgd_select(self, select):
    self.r_label.setPixmap(QPixmap('ui/images/r_white.png'))
    self.n_label.setPixmap(QPixmap('ui/images/n_white.png'))
    self.d_label.setPixmap(QPixmap('ui/images/d_white.png'))
    self.p_label.setPixmap(QPixmap('ui/images/p_white.png'))

    if select == 'R':
        self.r_label.setPixmap(QPixmap('ui/images/r_green.png'))
    elif select == 'N':
        self.n_label.setPixmap(QPixmap('ui/images/n_green.png'))
    elif select == 'D':
        self.d_label.setPixmap(QPixmap('ui/images/d_green.png'))
    else:
        self.p_label.setPixmap(QPixmap('ui/images/p_green.png'))

# Red power bar
def power_bar_enable(self, enable):
    if enable:
        self.red_power_label.setHidden(False)
    else:
        self.red_power_label.setHidden(True)

# Yellow normal mode bare
def normal_bar_enable(self, enable):
    if enable:
        self.ev_mode_bar_label.setHidden(True)
        self.normal_mode_bar_label.setHidden(False)
    else:
        self.normal_mode_bar_label.setHidden(True)

# EV mode bar
def ev_bar_enable(self, enable):
    if enable:
        self.normal_mode_bar_label.setHidden(True)
        self.ev_mode_bar_label.setHidden(False)
    else:
        self.ev_mode_bar_label.setHidden(True)

# Charging bar
def charging_bar_enable(self, enable):
    if enable:
        self.charging_bar_label.setHidden(False)
    else:
        self.charging_bar_label.setHidden(True)

# Selec yellow bar
def ef_bar_select(self, full):
    if full:
        self.bar_label.setPixmap(QPixmap('ui/images/full_bar.png'))
    else:
        self.bar_label.setPixmap(QPixmap('ui/images/half_bar.png'))
        

# READY or not
def ready_set(self, enable):
    if enable:
        self.ready_label.setHidden(False)
        self.ready_label.setPixmap(QPixmap('ui/images/ready.png'))
    else:
        self.ready_label.setHidden(True)

# EV Normal Power
def power_mode(self, mode):
    self.eco_label.setHidden(True)
    self.ev_mode_label.setHidden(True)
    self.normal_mode_label.setHidden(True)
    self.power_mode_label.setHidden(True)

    if mode == 'E':
        self.eco_label.setHidden(False)
        self.ev_mode_label.setHidden(False)
    elif mode == 'N':
        self.eco_label.setHidden(False)
        self.normal_mode_label.setHidden(False)
    else:
        self.power_mode_label.setHidden(False)

# Change battery
def battery_update(self, percent):
    self.battery_progressBar.setValue(percent)

@pyqtSlot(int)
def __update_mode(self, mode):
    print(f"Change to mode {mode}")

    if mode == 0:
        self.rgd_select('N')
        self.ready_set(True)

    elif mode == 1 or mode == 2:
        self.battery_update(100)
        self.rgd_select('D')
        self.speed_label.setText("30")
        self.motor1_speed_label.setText("10")
        self.motor2_speed_label.setText("20")
        self.motor3_speed_label.setText("30")
        self.motor1_torque_label.setText("2")
        self.motor2_torque_label.setText("4")
        self.motor3_torque_label.setText("6")
        print("Play video x")
        self.play_video('x')

    elif mode == 3 or mode == 4:
        self.battery_update(5)
        self.rgd_select('D')
        self.speed_label.setText("30")
        self.motor1_speed_label.setText("10")
        self.motor2_speed_label.setText("20")
        self.motor3_speed_label.setText("30")
        self.motor1_torque_label.setText("2")
        self.motor2_torque_label.setText("4")
        self.motor3_torque_label.setText("6")
        print("Play video z")
        self.play_video('z')

    elif mode == 5 or mode == 6:
        self.battery_update(50)
        self.rgd_select('D')
        self.speed_label.setText("30")
        self.motor1_speed_label.setText("10")
        self.motor2_speed_label.setText("20")
        self.motor3_speed_label.setText("30")
        self.motor1_torque_label.setText("2")
        self.motor2_torque_label.setText("4")
        self.motor3_torque_label.setText("6")
        if mode == 5:
            print("Play video xy")
            self.play_video('xy')
        else:
            print("Play video xyz")
            self.play_video('xyz')

    elif mode == 7 or mode == 8:
        self.battery_update(100)
        self.rgd_select('R')
        self.ready_set(True)
        self.speed_label.setText(" 0")
        self.motor1_speed_label.setText(" 0")
        self.motor2_speed_label.setText(" 0")
        self.motor3_speed_label.setText(" 0")
        self.motor1_torque_label.setText(" 0")
        self.motor2_torque_label.setText(" 0")
        self.motor3_torque_label.setText(" 0")
        print("Play video zzz")
        self.play_video('zzz')

    elif mode == 9 or mode == 10:
        self.battery_update(100)
        self.rgd_select('P')
        self.ready_set(True)
        self.speed_label.setText(" 0")
        self.motor1_speed_label.setText(" 0")
        self.motor2_speed_label.setText(" 0")
        self.motor3_speed_label.setText(" 0")
        self.motor1_torque_label.setText(" 0")
        self.motor2_torque_label.setText(" 0")
        self.motor3_torque_label.setText(" 0")
        if mode == 9:
            self.battery_update(5)
            print("Play video xyz")
            self.play_video('xyz')
        else:
            self.battery_update(100)
            print("Play video yz")
            self.play_video('yz')
    
    elif mode == 11 or mode == 12:
        self.battery_update(1)
        self.rgd_select('P')
        self.ready_set(True)
        self.speed_label.setText("30")
        self.motor1_speed_label.setText("10")
        self.motor2_speed_label.setText("20")
        self.motor3_speed_label.setText("30")
        self.motor1_torque_label.setText("2")
        self.motor2_torque_label.setText("4")
        self.motor3_torque_label.setText("6")
        print("Play video x")
        self.play_video('x')
        if mode == 11:
            self.battery_update(100)
        else:
            self.battery_update(5)
```

Tried by adding loops or time delays but the GUI stopped functioning.

Tried by adding loops or time delays but the GUI stopped functioning.